# Pandas.DataFrame: efficient way to add a column "seconds since last event"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas.DataFrame with a standard index representing seconds, and I want to add a column "seconds elapsed since last event" where the events are given in a list. Specifically, say

```
event = [2, 5]
```

and

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((7, 1)))
|    |   0 |
|---:|----:|
|  0 |   0 |
|  1 |   0 |
|  2 |   0 |
|  3 |   0 |
|  4 |   0 |
|  5 |   0 |
|  6 |   0 |
```

Then I want to obtain

```
|    |   0 |    x |
|---:|----:|-----:|
|  0 |   0 | <NA> |
|  1 |   0 | <NA> |
|  2 |   0 |    0 |
|  3 |   0 |    1 |
|  4 |   0 |    2 |
|  5 |   0 |    0 |
|  6 |   0 |    1 |
```

I tried

```
df["x"] = pd.Series(range(5)).shift(2)

|    |   0 |   x |
|---:|----:|----:|
|  0 |   0 | nan |
|  1 |   0 | nan |
|  2 |   0 |   0 |
|  3 |   0 |   1 |
|  4 |   0 |   2 |
|  5 |   0 | nan |
|  6 |   0 | nan |
```

so apparently to make it work I need to write `df["x"] = pd.Series(range(5+2)).shift(2)`.

More importantly, when I then do `df["x"] = pd.Series(range(2+5)).shift(5)` I obtain

```
|    |   0 |   x |
|---:|----:|----:|
|  0 |   0 | nan |
|  1 |   0 | nan |
|  2 |   0 | nan |
|  3 |   0 | nan |
|  4 |   0 | nan |
|  5 |   0 |   0 |
|  6 |   0 |   1 |
```

That is: the previous has been overwritten. Is there a way to assign new values without overwriting existing values by nan ?
Then, I can do something like

```
for i in event:
    df["x"] = pd.Series(range(len(df))).shift(i)
```

Or is there a more efficient way ?

For the record, here is my naive code. It works, but looks inefficient and of poor design:

```
c = 1000000
df["x"] = c
if event:
    idx = 0
    for i in df.itertuples():
        print(i)
        if idx < len(event) and i.Index == event[idx]:
            c = 0
            idx += 1
        df.loc[i.Index, "x"] = c
        c += 1
return df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do double groupby:

```
s = df.index.isin(event).cumsum()
# or equivalently
# s = df.loc[event, 0].reindex(df.index).isna().cumsum()

df['x'] = np.where(s>0,df.groupby(s).cumcount(), np.nan)
```

Output:

```
     0    x
0  0.0  NaN
1  0.0  NaN
2  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  1.0
4  0.0  2.0
5  0.0  0.0
6  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks. And for the column "time to next even", from your answer, I deduce: t = df[::-1].index.isin(event).cumsum()[::-1]
; df['y'] = np.where(t>0,df.groupby(t).cumcount(ascending=False), np.nan)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try  this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((7, 1)))
event = [2, 5]

df.loc[event, 0] = 1
df = df.replace(0, np.nan)

grp=df[0].cumsum().ffill()
df['x'] = df.groupby(grp).cumcount().mask(grp.isna())
df
```

Output:

```
|    |   0 |   x |
|---:|----:|----:|
|  0 | nan | nan |
|  1 | nan | nan |
|  2 |   1 |   0 |
|  3 | nan |   1 |
|  4 | nan |   2 |
|  5 |   1 |   0 |
|  6 | nan |   1 |
```